# C++ Pointers/References

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, reference

This code takes coordinates from mouse click and creates a new vertex;

```
void DrawingWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
   if(getCurrentState()==ADD_VERTEX){
      x=event->x();
      y=event->y();

      Vertex p1 {&x,&y};
      m_mainWindow->addVertex(p1);
      update();
   }
}
```

Here is Vertex class code:

```
class Vertex {

public:

   float *x = 0;
   float *y = 0;

   Vertex() = default;
   Vertex(float *nx, float *ny);
};
```

All Verces are held in list:

```
QList<Vector2> vertexList;
```

And addVertex(Vertex vertex):

```
addVertex(Vertex vertex){
   vertexList << vertex;
}
```

Basically first vertex adding works perfectly, but when I'm trying to add second vertex(using the given method), first vertex coordinates are changed instead.

NB! Coordinates of Vertex class are intentionally pointers, because by using another method I'm changing their coords.

What am I missing?

Comment: Re: "Coordinates of Vertex class are intentionally pointers, because by using another method I'm changing their coords." - Wait, what? There's nothing about what you've just described that requires making `x` and `y` pointers to `float`. Honestly `x` and `y` really should be just direct members of `Vertex` if you want sane code.

Comment: Nothing says the `event` variable will be unchanged after the function has finished, and you're storing pointers to its values. Either you'll keep pointing to the latest values, or you'll end up pointing to rubbish values / freed memory. It's up to the compiler/OS which happens. Summary: don't do that.

Comment: Consider adding getters/setters to `Vertex` and manipulating coordinates with these methods, rather than storing a pointer to some outer scope which can change these coordinates in unknown way or even invalidate these pointers resulting in crash. Your current implementation is asking for trouble, it is unsafe, bug-prone, and badly designed in general.

Comment: QMouseEvent's `x` and `y` are ints, so it is unnecessary to store them as floats. And there is already a class to store integer coordinate pairs: [QPoint](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpoint.html). If you really need floats, there is [QVector2D](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvector2d.html).

Answer (score 3):

`x` and `y` in your code are probably fields of `DrawingWidget` and in `Vertex` you are storing pointers always to same variables (those fields). So in `vertexList` you have always the same values of pointers to the same fields.
I don't understand why you are surprised by your code behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The code in your question and the behavior you observe implies you have something like this:

```
class DrawingWidget
{
public:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
private:
    float x;
    float y;
    // ...
};
```

And when the function `mousePressEvent()` is called, you're assigning the new coordinates to those members:

```
void DrawingWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
   if(getCurrentState()==ADD_VERTEX){
      x=event->x();
      y=event->y();
...
```

So everytime you press the mouse, you're *overwriting* the old coordinates. Now, this might have not been a problem, but since the `Vertex`s you add to the list contains *pointers* to those class members, instead of simply storing a copy of the coordinates, the first vertex appears to have changed coordinates.

The way to deal with this is to not use pointers at all (at least for your classes)!

```
class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex() : x(0.0f), y(0.0f) {}
    Vertex(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    float getX() const { return x; }
    float getY() const { return y; }

    void setX(float x) { this->x = x; }
    void setY(float y) { this->y = y; }

private:
   float x; // NOT pointers!
   float y;
};

class DrawingWidget
{
public:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
private:
    //float x; // Not needed!
    //float y;
    // ...
};

void DrawingWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
   if(getCurrentState()==ADD_VERTEX) {
      Vertex p1{event->x(), event->y()};
      m_mainWindow->addVertex(p1);
      update();
   }
}
```

Comment: How can I change X and Y then?

Comment: @Ricardo Simmus: You can write getter/setter functions for the `Vertex` (see updated example).

Comment: @Ricardo Simmus: It's not a stupid question at all. Just a misguided one. :-)